# Sharing an image from RecyclerView

Tags: android, imageview, android-recyclerview

My target is to share the image from `ImageView` inside `RecyclerView`
The image is loaded from Internet using `Picasso` lib

I have added a Share button below each item
setted the onclick function properly
but cant proceed further.

I have this data adapter :

```
 package com.myapp.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.myapp.app.model.AndroidVersion;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android;
    private Context context;
    private ImageView content;



    public DataAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android) {
        this.android = android;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {


        viewHolder.tv_name.setText(android.get(i).getName());
        viewHolder.tv_version.setText(android.get(i).getVer());
        Picasso.with(context).load(android.get(i).getApi()).into(viewHolder.img_android);
        Picasso.with(context).load(android.get(i).getImage()).into(viewHolder.image_android);


        viewHolder.btshare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /// button click event
                content = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image_android);
                content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(content.getDrawingCache());
                File cachePath = new File("/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg");
                try {
                    cachePath.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(cachePath);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
                    ostream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                Uri phototUri = Uri.parse("/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg");
                share.setData(phototUri);
                share.setType("image/*");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, phototUri);
                v.getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"Share via"));


        }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return android.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView tv_name,tv_version;
        private ImageView img_android,image_android;
        private Button btshare;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            btshare = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btshare);
            tv_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            tv_version = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_version);
            img_android = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img_android);
            image_android = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image_android);


        }
    }


}
```

It force closes the app whenever i onclick  fires

please help

This is the error log line:

```
08-08 21:10:59.956 8934-8934/com.myapp.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapp.app, PID: 8934
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'void android.widget.ImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
at com.myapp.app.DataAdapter$1.onClick(DataAdapter.java:60)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5232)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21289)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Comment: can you post stacktrace too.

Comment: added the error line

Comment: try chagning     `content = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image_android);` by `content =  viewHolder.getImage_android()` because now you are looking for your imageview inside your Button view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple to solve.

Just change

```
content = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image_android);
```

to

```
content = viewHolder.image_android;
```

Because you are referring to the wrong `View` in here `v.findViewById(R.id.image_android)`

Here `v` refers to the `Button` view and you are trying to find inside the Button. **But your actual image is not inside the Button**, is it?

Just refer to the `image_android` from the ViewHolder, where it is correctly referenced. **It won't be null anymore**.

Comment: Thanks it works.. but now another problem -- when i click the share button it is picking up incorrect images from the recycler view.. can you guide me further?

Comment: Yes, would love to help you further. But it should be a different question. Just ask a new question and link me. Thanks. :-)

Comment: here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854039/share-button-in-recyclerview-picking-up-wrong-images

Answer (score 1):

change `content = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image_android)` to

```
content = (ImageView) viewholder.image_android;
```

Your imageView is within itemView and code is trying to find it within button.

Answer (score -1):

Set the `OncLickListener` in the `ViewHolder`,not in  `onBindViewHolder`.